# Dash to Dock requires restart when suspended or auto screen-off

Tags: dash-to-dock

I need to restart Dash to Dock whenever I come back from Suspend mode or auto screen-off.
I restart it by running “r” command via ALT+F2.

Comment: It is one of many bugs in dash to dock, If I am not wrong you are on gnome 40 (21.10) right? When dash to dock will be updated, probably this would be fixed

Comment: Ohh! I am using gnome 3.36 with Ubuntu 20.04. Any alert native you suggest to use?

Comment: You can probably try alternatives of the dash to dock! IMHO you should use dash to panel and many more but I cannot suggest an exact alt because IDK how you use the dock

Comment: Also, It will help future readers if you provide OS details, a screenshot, the gnome shell version and other details like some extra packages you use to c9nf8g gnome :-)

Answer (score 0):

Disable ubuntu dock in the Extensions app.  they are conflictng